# Increment value in row if it exists, otherwise create row with value?

Tags: mysql, insert, row, if-not-exists

Below is the MySQL table layout that I'm working with.  Basically, I'd like to increment views, watchers, and inquiries as they occur through the front end of the website.  My question is how would I go about having a new _views row for instance created upon the first visit to ID: 1106 or 1107 with a MySQL insert?

```
ID          key         value
-----       -----       ------
1104        _reserve    10000
1104        _views      100
1104        _watchers   2
1104        _inquiries  1
1105        _reserve    1500
1106        _reserve    24000
1106        _views      236
1107        _reserve    45300
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ID,`key`,`value`) VALUES (1106,'_views',1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = `value` + 1;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ID,`key`,`value`) VALUES (1107,'_views',1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = `value` + 1;
```

If your table has `value` defined as

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
   ...
   value INT DEFAULT 1,
   ...
);
```

then the INSERTs would be

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ID,`key`) VALUES (1106,'_views')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = `value` + 1;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ID,`key`) VALUES (1107,'_views')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = `value` + 1;
```

Comment: I'll test it out and let you know.

Comment: Doesn't quite work as I don't believe there is a unique key.

Comment: The unique key needs to be (ID,key) for this to work. Sorry, I should have said that earlier.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Is this better then a select by keys and then running an additional query?